# What is the meaning of %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ in a RewriteCond?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've come across

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$

Does this just mean "not empty"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, all that that line is doing is ensuring that the REFERER header is not empty. Logically, recall that `$` indicates simply the end of a string to be matched, so this `!^` is just ensuring there isn't nothing there.

Comment: What wasn't clear to me was that the ! applies to the entire condition, not just the first character of the condition.   So it's:  NOT  ^$.    A clearer example is !\.(gif|jpg|png)$ which is NOT   a .gif, .jpg, or .png.  Thanks

Comment: @Steve No worries, the syntax is a little strange.  If this helped an upvote is always appreciated! :)